# Why does my navigation bar not go the entire width of the website?

Tags: html, css, navigation

The container width on CSS is 100% but it stops a bit before the end of the page.

HTML Used

```
<div id="nav-container">
    <ul id ="nav-list">
        <li id="nav-title">lymbo</li>
        <li><a href="#">Playmaps</a></li>
        <li><a href="../map.html">Map</a></li>
        <li><a href="../about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

CSS Used

```
#nav-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    float: top;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    background-color: rgba(0, 70, 12, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

Also if anyone has any idea why my headers keep interfering with my navigation bar I'd like to hear your input.  I wanted my navigation bar to have a bit of a "gradient" to it like the Twitter navigation bar but the tutorial I used came close but no dice.

Comment: it's easier to analyze if you upload a scren or post a link to a demo of it... also, `top` isn't an actual value for `float`.

We need to see more of your html and css

Comment: green color is filling the full width right then what is the problem

Comment: `float: top;` :O CSS5?

Answer (score 3):

In #nav-container, add margin and position control, like this:

```
#nav-container {
    margin:0px auto;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

And since you're using a list for your navigation, you should add CSS to control the margin for the list, like this:

```
#nav-list {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
}
```

`list-style-type:none;` will remove the bullets points in the list (if preferred).

Lastly, for some browsers it might be wise to set the margins to zero in the `<body>` tag, like this:

```
<body leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" bottommargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `left: 0;` to your CSS. Also as others have mentioned, you don't need the `float` property.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see the JSFiddle, I can't test it.

But I think the div is already on the full width of the page.
It might be the list that's not on 100% of the page yet.
Put a width:100% in there aswell and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet that your `nav-container` is inside another div (`container-fluid`) which has a `padding-left` applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Default elements have some space around them.  That is why it is common to use a reset style.  Add this to the beginning of your main style sheet, because it is a good practice all around.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```